# Basic PHP form submitting PowerShell

Tags: php, forms, powershell, submit

I'm trying to create a basic form for running PowerShell scripts. I've looked around and there is a great solution by Robin running PowerShell scripts using IIS and PHP.
Source: http://theboywonder.co.uk/2012/07/29/executing-powershell-using-php-and-iis/
I ran a test with his own code but modifying the path variable with my own PS script, which went fine.

I'm now trying to create just a basic form which just has a submit function that onclick will run the PS script and return the results back to the same page.

Here's the slightly modified PHP code I took from his sample.

```
<?php
// If there was no submit variable passed to the script (i.e. user has visited the page without clicking submit), display the form:
if(!isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
?>
<form name="testForm" id="testForm" action="pstest4.php" method="post">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Do stuff" />
</form>
<?php    
}
// Else if submit was pressed, check if all of the required variables have a value:
elseif((isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
// Get the variables submitted by POST in order to pass them to the PowerShell script:
// Path to the PowerShell script. Remember double backslashes:
$psScriptPath = "\\\\appswebfront\\Scripts\\mock.ps1";

// Execute the PowerShell script, passing the parameters:
$query = shell_exec("powershell -command $psScriptPath < NUL");
echo $query;    
}
?>
```

I run that and I get:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in \\APPSWEBFRONT\INETPUB\wwwroot\pstest4.php on line 31`

Line 31 in my preview is where it begins with $psScriptPath.

Of course, if I delete the semi-colon, it'll simply go to the next one, up to the point when it'd say `unexpected $query' (T_VARIABLE)`.

I'm sure there is some incorrect syntax somewhere, but as I'm purely a beginner in PHP, I don't know where I'm going wrong.

At the end of the day, I need the page to show the form when the submit button is not clicked/posted, and upon click, it'd run the PS script and return the output back to the same page.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many brackets on this line `elseif((isset($_POST["submit"]))`

Should be `elseif(isset($_POST["submit"]))`.

Try that and let us know.